# VBA: Execute Context Menu functionality that is not native to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sap-analysis-for-office

I would like to execute a context menu option that is available as part of an Excel add-in (`SAP Analysis for Office`) and is not native to Excel. The following piece of code only lists out context menu option that are native to Excel. As a result I there's no way for me to execute these non-native controls available.

```
   While x < Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Count
     Debug.Print Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(x).Caption
     x = x + 1
   Wend
```

How can I execute the functions behind the `Collapse` and `Expand to Level` => `Level 0X` context menu options non-native to Excel?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this works with this particular Add-On but have you tried recording a macro while executing the function?

Comment: @horst, thanks for your reply. I tried that but it didn't record anything meaningful.